# can I have a UIButton with UIWebView contents?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, uibutton

I'd like to have buttons that have the text formatting capabilities of a UIWebView. Is this possible to do easily by subclassing UIButton, or am I better off with a different approach? If at all possible, I'd rather be able to benefit from the functionality in UIButton rather than subclass UIControl and reimplement button functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIButton is a so called class cluster. This means that once you've instantiated a button, you're not getting an instance of UIButton but of some private internal class (see also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920045/subclassing-uibutton-but-cant-access-my-properties)). So the best way really is to subclass from UIControl, I'm afraid. Search StackOverflow for UIButton subclassing, there are already a lot of questions related to it that might explain this in more detail.

**Edit**: You *can* subclass UIButton but it seems to be problematic.

Comment: Thanks for that info. I wonder if one solution might be to create a uiview subclass that layers a non-interactive uiwebview over top of a button whose text is empty.