# how to set UIButton type in UIButton Subclass

Tags: ios, uibutton, subclass

I am subclassing the UIButton, what i want is to set the button type to Round Rect.

Button.h

```
@interface Button : UIButton {}
    - (void)initialize;
@end
```

Button.m

```
@implementation Button

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}


-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self){
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)initialize
{
    self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
    self.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
   //[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
}

@end
```

Here i tried `[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]` but it doesn't work. Can anyone suggest how to make it work?

I know in many previous post it has been said that Subclassing UIButton is not recommended, but the fact that in Developer's Docs there is no mention about NOT subclassing it.

Comment: What I you *really* trying to do? I know, you said, you want to set the button's type, but I don't believe you. You have an idea for your UI and you try to reach it with subclassing UIButton and setting its type..., but you won't. So tell us, what you are going for, and I'm sure there'll be a solution different from your approach.

Comment: but you _won't_.. :s
well, nothing so special, just creating the subclass so that i could manipulate the buttons throughout the app..!

Comment: @HarisHussain Why do you need a subclass to manipulate buttons? The UIButton interface seems sufficient for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subclass UIButton to add a property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500327/subclass-uibutton-to-add-a-property). Also [create unbutton subclass](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5045672/643383) and [Subclassing UIButton but can't access my properties](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2920045/643383).

Comment: So that the buttons remain consistant throughout the app. So that when i have to change font size of all the buttons i do not have to change it everywhere i have used one. etc.

Comment: So how about a constant like `#define BUTTON_FONT [UIFont fontWithName:aFontName size:aFontSize]`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may find the discussion at CocoaBuilder's thread [How to subclass UIButton?](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/284622-how-to-subclass-uibutton.html) helpful, particularly [Jack Nutting's suggestion to ignore the buttonType](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/284622-how-to-subclass-uibutton.html#284656):

> Note that this way the buttonType isn't explicitly set to anything,
>   which probably means that it's UIButtonTypeCustom.  The Docs don't
>   seem to actually specify that, but since that's the 0 value in the
>   enum, that's likely what happens (and that seems to be the observable
>   behavior as well)

Answer (score 17):

## `UIButton` subclass in Swift

*The following code works in Swift 3 and above.

You cannot set the `buttonType` of a `UIButton` subclass by design. It is automatically set to `custom` which means you get a plain appearance and behavior as a starting point.

If you want to reuse code that sets the button's appearance, you can do this without subclassing. One approach is by providing factory methods that create a `UIButton` and set visual properties.

### Example factory method to avoid subclassing

```
extension UIButton {
    static func createStandardButton() -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.gray, for: .highlighted)
        return button
    }
}

let button = UIButton.createStandardButton()
```

I avoid subclassing `UIButton` when other customization techniques suffice. The factory method example is one option. There are other options including the UIAppearance API, etc.

Sometimes there are customization needs that require subclassing. For example, I've created `UIButton` subclasses to take fine control over how the button animates in response to touch events or to have the button call a predefined delegate or closure when tapped (as opposed to assigning a `#selector` to each instance).

The following is a basic `UIButton` subclass example as a starting point.

### Example UIButton Subclass

```
internal class CustomButton: UIButton {

    init() {
        // The frame can be set outside of the initializer. Default to zero.
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        initialize()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        // Called when instantiating from storyboard or nib
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initialize()
    }

    func initialize() {
        print("Execute common initialization code")
    }
}

let button = CustomButton()
print(button.buttonType == .custom)  // true
```

### A note about `UIButtonType`

Since the question was asked in 2012, `UIButtonType.roundedRect` has been deprecated. The header file comments say to use `UIButtonType.system` instead.

The following is from UIButton.h converted to Swift in Xcode

```
public enum UIButtonType : Int {

    case custom // no button type

    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    case system // standard system button

    case detailDisclosure
    case infoLight
    case infoDark
    case contactAdd

    public static var roundedRect: UIButtonType { get } // Deprecated, use UIButtonTypeSystem instead
}
```

#### And here's the critical info for setting the so-called "Style" setting seen in a storyboard drop-down menu:

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72913854/294884

Comment: Not that I'm a fan of storyboards, but the factory method doesn't really work with storyboards. Other than that, it's a really nice strategy.

Comment: This is a great old answer.  It's completely true that you're almost always better-off not subclassing UIButton.  @MobileDan I took the liberty of adding some critical new info at the end for your perusing TY

Answer (score 12):

not quite what you're looking for, but remember that your subclass still has the buttonWithType method, and it works fine.

buttonWithType calls your subclasses initWithFrame, and sets the type appropriately.

```
SubclassButton *myButton=[SubclassButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

Comment: You saved my day!

Comment: Thing is that is a convenience init and you can't either override or call super class convenience init( before self).

Comment: @AmberK any overriding you need to do should be done in initWithFrame. SubclassButton.init(type: .roundedRect) returns a button of type SubclassButton.

Comment: Okay so the super convenience init of button type will call my overridden designated init(frame:). Thanks now I get it :)

Answer (score 6):

Creating a convenience init worked for me:

```swift
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    
    convenience init() {
        self.init(type: .system)
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        /*Do customization here*/
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        
        /*Do customization here*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant answer.  For anyone reading, note that you don't *need* the second two clauses, only if you are doing further customization.  Adding convenience `init() { self.init(type: .system) }` alone does the trick.  Look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72913854/294884 to know how to set the equally bizarre so-called "style" value.

Answer (score 3):

Since the original intend is to configure the button at the initialization point, you can declare a helper initializer and pass the configuration like:

```
extension UIButton {
    convenience init(type: ButtonType, configuration(UIButton) -> ()) {
        self.init(type: type)
        configuration(self)
    }
}
```

This will initialize a button with the given type and perform any configuration on it before returning the new initialized button.

###### ️ Usage:

```
let myButton = UIButton(type: .contactAdd) {
    $0.tintColor = .red
}
```

#### Make a consistent style for all buttons?

You can make a configuration function and pass it for all of your buttons:

```
func consistentConfiguration(_ button: UIButton) -> () {
    button.tintColor = .red
}

let myConsistentButton1 = UIButton(type: .contactAdd, configuration: consistentConfiguration)
let myConsistentButton2 = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure, configuration: consistentConfiguration)
```

<sub>⚠️ You can turn this configuration into another helper initializer but its not recommended since it is not scoped to correct place</sub>

Answer (score 1):

With iOS7, this is more relevant than before, as sometimes you *need* to use UIButtonTypeSystem, and you can't simply override init and do [MyButton alloc] init], because then it's a UIButtonTypeCustom, which doesn't reflect tintColor nor have nice highlight fade effects.

To subclass, make a static constructor like so:

```
+ (instancetype)myButtonWithTitle:(NSString *)title imageNamed:(NSString *)imageName target:(id)target action:(SEL)action {
    MyButton *button = [self buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    ... my custom setup for title, image, target, etc ...
    return button;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely subclass UIButton.  I have successfully created a DateButton which looks like a UITextField but when the user touches it it displays a DatePicker in a Popover.  Has a property for storing the Date, etc.  Let me know if the above never solved your problem and I'll post details more.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good solution, so we need to 'thank' the Apple for use this crutch. XD

```
//if self.buttonType == .system && self.state.contains(.highlighted) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.05) {
        self.titleLabel?.alpha = 1.0
    }
//}
```

Add in `touchesBegan(...)` for example.

Answer (score -2):

What about this?

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
    self = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; 
    if (self) {
        self.frame = frame;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: That gives you an instance of UIButton, not an instance of the subclass. So, for example, any additional ivars that the subclass adds won't be there.

Comment: [UIRoundedRectButton initialize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8a406a0

Comment: it work on initWithFrame  but how to work on InitWithCoder?     otherwise   please retain it or it leaks~~

Comment: This doesn't work either.. i have tried so many iterations :P

Comment: @HarisHussain `+initialize` is a class method, not an instance method. See [Objective-C: init vs. initialize](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6191515/643383) for an explanation. Using an instance method with the same name might work, but it also might be part of your problem.