# Custom UIButton setSelected weird behavior

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm new to swift and I'm just trying to create a subclass of uibutton. Except that I have this weird blue rounded rect appearing when the button is selected as shown below. When all I want is a nice white border.

[image]

The code of my class :

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

@IBDesignable
class ColorButton: UIButton {
    //MARK: PROPERTIES
    @IBInspectable var stickerColor: UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor() {
        didSet {
            configure()
        }
    }

    override var selected: Bool {
        willSet(newValue) {
            super.selected = newValue;
            if selected {
                layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            } else {
                layer.borderWidth = 0.0
            }
        }
    }

    //MARK: Initializers
    override init(frame : CGRect) {
        super.init(frame : frame)
        setup()
        configure()
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame:CGRectZero)
        setup()
        configure()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
        configure()
    }


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setup()
        configure()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        setup()
        configure()
    }

    func setup() {
        //Border color
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        //Corner Radius
        setUpCornerRadius()
    }

    func configure() {
        backgroundColor = stickerColor
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setUpCornerRadius()
    }

    func setUpCornerRadius() {
        layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetWidth(bounds) * 0.205
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have checked your code. and I got same issue.

but If you set button type as Custom then this problem will not occur
[image]

Output :

[image]

Found something for `buttonType` :

You may find the discussion at CocoaBuilder's thread [How to subclass UIButton?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjQLi.png) helpful, particularly [Jack Nutting's suggestion to ignore the buttonType](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv2zR.png):

> Note that this way the buttonType isn't explicitly set to anything,
>   which probably means that it's UIButtonTypeCustom.  The Docs don't
>   seem to actually specify that, but since that's the 0 value in the
>   enum, that's likely what happens (and that seems to be the observable
>   behavior as well)

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10278515/3202193

Comment: @AmbroiseCollon :) Welcome anytime :)

Comment: @AmbroiseCollon you are looking at the result of the 'tintColor' - if you don't want to change to custom button simply set tintColor to clearColor